# C++ classes, confusion in reguards to #ifdef, #define and #endif

Tags: c++

Ok, so we are covering classes in my C++ class, and  in last lecture we learned that if you #include the same class in a same file multiple times bad things can happened, and the way to prevent this is to use #ifdef, #define and #endif in header files. so here is just a simple program that I am trying to write, and because of this guys #, it fails. It seems like the code after #ifdef is being ignored by a compailer. WHat is the problem here ?

Here is the program, it consists of 3 files, also note that I am aware that without the # things in .h file program works correctly, and that in this particular program, I dont even need them. I am working on big project where I need to use them, and they just dont work.

Thank you.

==========Main File===========

```
#include "Circle.h"

int main()
{
    Circle C(5);

    C.output();

    return 0;
}
```

========Circle.h file==========

```
#ifdef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circle
{
public:
    Circle(int);
    void output();

private:

    int n;


};


#endif
```

========Circle.cpp file========

```
#include "Circle.h"


Circle::Circle(int numb)
{
    n=numb;
}



void Circle::output()
{

    cout<<"The number is "<<n<<endl;

}
```

Comment: You want `#ifndef`: If the macro is *not yet defined* then proceed. With `#ifdef`, it will *never* succeed.

Comment: Yea, in your code, `include guards` will be created only if they are already created. That's why you need use `#ifndef` instead `#ifdef`.

Comment: Also, please move `using namespace std;` from all headers to source files, after the last `#include`. That's how it's supposed to be used. In headers always use full names (`std::string` instead of `string`).

Comment: Instead of the awkward but formally standard `#ifndef` internal include guards, just use de facto standard `#pragma once` at top of each header. Just keep in mind that, like much else, it probably doesn't work with IBM's AIX compiler, whatever it's called now. Essentially, just make support for `#pragma once` an absolute requirement for your tools; I doubt that it would exclude more than that single low quality compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `#ifndef CIRCLE_H` instead of `#ifdef CIRCLE_H`. It means "if not defined".

Comment: Thank you so much, dumb me, I did not noticed that there was an n during the lecture.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you used wrong preprocessor construct:

```
#ifdef CIRCLE_H //#ifdef is not the right one!
#define CIRCLE_H

//...

#endif
```

You should use **#ifndef** instead. Why?

`#ifdef` means `if token with name, placed after this instruction is already defined, then...`. Do you think this will work? When you include this file, `CIRCLE_H` is not defined anywhere, so `#ifdef CIRCLE_H` will always evaluate to false and content between `#ifdef` and `#endif` will be always discarded.

But when you write this:

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H

//...

#endif
```

You say: `if CIRCLE_H has not yet been defined` (which is true, when file is included for the first time), `then define CIRCLE_H and proceed`. `CIRCLE_H` is then defined and every next include will not pass this `#ifndef` because `CIRCLE_H` will be already there.